# Android Home Launcher, add a activity with icon in Launcher

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, launcher, android-launcher

I have created a custom launcher and its perfectly working fine.Now i want to add an activity to it which shall be launched like any other app from launcher.

Here is my Manifest file.

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.sample.launcher2.Launcher"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:resumeWhilePausing="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.sample.launcher2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/application_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_home">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am not able to launch activity from launcher.How can i achieve it ?

Comment: I've never built a launcher before, so I might be wrong, but don't you need the category `Launcher` too?

Comment: @user2340612 its not needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Make following changes hope it will work
<activity
        android:name="com.sample.launcher2.Launcher"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:resumeWhilePausing="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sample.launcher2.Launcher" />//Here the change
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.sample.launcher2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/application_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_home">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thats worked for me. But the problem now is that the launcher not started with OS boot...Any idea what wrong?

Comment: Please add the home and default category in the intent filter, other option could be to use BroadcastReceiver and listen to Boot Event. I have updated the code to include more categories in the intent filter. Hope that helps thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing that activity's launch mode to singleTask may help!